# Help me with a simple question about open $\mathbb{R}$ sets

Tags: real-analysis

For every $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R} - X$ is open?

Need this to be true to proof $\mathbb{R} = int(X) \cup int(\mathbb{R}-X) \cup fr(X)$

Comment: Let $A$ be any non-open set and let $X = \mathbb{R}-A$.

Comment: I thought that I knew what your notation meant, but now I have no idea. It seems you're taking the union of a number (that may not exist), another number (that may not exist), and a subset of $\Bbb R$ (that may be empty), and trying to prove that this "union" is somehow all of $\Bbb R$? Please clarify, because this makes no sense, as currently written.

Comment: Sorry! I meant $int(X)$ and $int(\mathbb{R}-X)$!

Comment: It is not true that $\mathbb{R} - X$ is open no matter what $X$ is. You need to think of another approach to the proof if you were hoping to depend on that. (For confused readers, I assume that $fr(X)$ is the boundary (frontier) of $X$.

Comment: Is $X$ a set? What do your operators $int$ and $fr$ mean?

Answer (score 0):

From the definitions of open and closed sets, if ${\mathbb R}\setminus X$ is open then $X$ must be closed (we know that ${\mathbb R}$ itself is clopen, so we can draw no additional conclusions there).  While it's possible that each such $X$ could *also* be clopen, a quick example disproves that: if $X=\overline{B(0,1)}$, the closed ball of unit radius centred at the origin, then $X$ is definitely not clopen, but ${\mathbb R}\setminus X$ is open.

So your hope is unfortunately smashed to smithereens.  However, all is not lost because you *don't* need this to be true to prove the claim you're interested in.  The interior of a set is, again by definition, always open, so $\mathrm{int}({\mathbb R}\setminus X)$ will be an open set whether or not $X$ is, and likewise ${\mathrm X}$.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!